# How to preserve special characters highlighting when converting to HTML?

Tags: vim

I have an issue with the `:TOhtml` command.

It works great, but it doesn't preserve the `list` option.

If I do:

```
:set list listchars=tab:>-,trail:.,extends:>
:TOhtml
```

The special characters highlight is missing in the generated HTML file.

Any idea how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This appears to be a [known bug](http://ftp.twaren.net/vim/runtime/plugin/tohtml.vim) with tohtml in vim, supposedly fixed in 7.3, but I can't be sure.  Since it is injecting the document between `pre` tags, any whitespace *should* be preserved; tohtml strips them.